# How I can efficiently check existence of a document in RavenDB

Tags: database, database-design, nosql, data-modeling, ravendb

I have a domain entity Contacts, Contact is associated with lists via the MemberOf property (contains the list id in RavenDB)

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public List<string> MemberOf { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use **RavenDB** to store contacts, one of the methods to upload contacts is via CSV files (in bulk). I was thinking how can I prevent duplicate data when two CSV files have the same contacts, I consider contacts to be the same when they have the same Email - this is related to my domain logic. A Contact can be a MemberOf two different CSV lists e.g. 
I am uploading two CSV lists that have the same email address field, the problem is that I want the contact class to have MemeberOf set to have two lists, this to keep me from having duplicate entries for each list, because the domain logic of my application required one contact object per email for statistical analysis.

Please challenge my design as well, I might not have the best data model here.

Thank you

Comment: How many docs will you be uploading per import, how many imports do you expect to run and how many docs do you expect to have in total?

Comment: did my answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only unique constraint that RavenDB enforces for you is the doc Id. So one method you can use is to make the email address the doc Id. You can then write code like this:

```
using (var session = docStore.OpenSession())
{
    foreach (var csvItemToImport in csvfile)
    {
        var existingDoc = session.Load<Contact>(csvItemToImport.Email);    
        if (existingDoc == null)
        {
            //No doc with the given email exists, add a new one
            session.Store(new Contact{ ... });
        }
        else
        {
            existingDoc.MemberOf.Add(csvItemToImport.ListName)
            // No need to store the doc, it's tracked in the session automatically
        }     
    }
    //Save the changes so far back to the dBase, in a single batched transaction
    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

Because the doc Id is the url (`/docs/contacts/blah@blah.co.uk`), you might have to do some escaping to account for the '@' in the email address.

and your POCO will look like this:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Id { get; set; } //this is actually an email address 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public List<string> MemberOf { get; set; }
}
```

**Update** if you don't want the doc Id to be the email address (for whatever reason). You can use the method [outlined here](http://richarddingwall.name/2012/03/06/quick-and-dirty-unique-constraints-in-raven-db/). It just stores 2 docs each time, the `Contact` doc and another doc that ensures the unique constraint.

Comment: I agree with this solution as long as each email address is a unique contact.  If you want to support the ability for email addresses to change and reflect the same contact, then you'll want a different Id.  Also, the session.Store() in the else block is redundant, as existingDoc is already tracked.  You can remove that line for a slight performance gain.  One last note, if you just want to check for document existence without loading the document, use session.Advanced.DatabaseCommands.Head().  It will just load the headers instead of the entire document.

Comment: Also see the "Update" section at the end for a way to allow the email address to change